# Error custom helper laravel 5.2, autoload files error

Tags: php, laravel

I have created custom helper laravel 5.2. I put in folder App/Helpers/Global.php.

and autoload files in composer.json :

```
"autoload": { 
   "files" : [
       "App/Helpers/Global.php"
   ]
}
```

On my Windows PC, it's working fine, but when i deploy to VPS centos I got this error.

```
PHP Warning:  require(/xxxx/xxxxx/public_html/xxxx/vendor/composer/../../App/Helpers/Global.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /xxxx/xxxx/public_html/xxxx/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
```

why Autoloading "files" is relative to vendor directory ?
Thanks in advance.

[error custom helper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol28c.png)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that OS on your VPS has case sensitive filename file system unlike Windows.
Just replace  `"App/Helpers/Global.php"` with  `"app/Helpers/Global.php"` and it should help.

Comment: It Works Andrej, thanx for your help.